Docker build or buildah: how do I set many env variables from a file?
I know several ways to set env variables while building an image: I can use ARG or ENV in Dockerfile.
Also I know I can pass text file with variables to docker run command and get env variables set this way: docker run --env-file=env_file_name alpine env
What I want to understand is how can I pass text file with env variables to by image during build. I.e. I want to use something like
docker build use-env-file=.env

or
buildah bud use-env-file=.env

Is it possible?

Neither docker build nor docker buildx build seem to support any options like this.  How many build arguments do you have; do you actually need so many?  (Should some or all of them be runtime environment settings so you can change them without rebuilding the image?)

Thats why I asked, I failed to find anything about env files during build.. I have 7-10 arguments, I dont want to specify them via ARG.
